# [google-maps-api-3][Geocoder] special characters: Ñ

Tags: api, maps, special-characters

I have a problem using geocoder for translate Address to Lang & Lng.
When I Send an Address whit the letter ñ or a special character (ó,é,í)
the geocoder not respond Ok.
How I can solve this?

My code:

```
     var Calle="Peña";//address name
     var Altura=3000;//number of the house
     var addr=Calle+" "+Altura + "Mar del Plata, Buenos Aires, Argentina";  
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: addr, region: 'ar'}, function(results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             var GeoPos=results[0].geometry.location;
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the character encoding is UTF-8. Otherwise Google's API will return the status code "INVALID_REQUEST".